# How to use tooltip bootstrap in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, tooltip

I'm working on project and I want to put a balloon tooltip like (html5) design on each textbox or another control

Here's an example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're working in a Windows Forms project. To add Tooltips controls have to use the ToolTip class.
You can add design-time control from the toolbox of Visual Studio. In this way the properties of each control, you will see a new property called ToolTip in which you can set the text you want to appear.
Another option is acerlo for programming, creating an instance of the ToolTip class.

More information:
[ToolTip Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: i don't  like the classic one i want new design using gui

Comment: @amine02 : Then design one, we aren't gonna code for you.

Comment: Here's a place to start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.ownerdraw(v=vs.110).aspx